# char* to SYSTEMTIME conversion with sscanf

Tags: c, winapi

With the example found in a website, I'm trying to convert a char* to a SYSTEMTIME structure :

```
SYSTEMTIME st;
char *dateHeure = (char*)calloc(30,1);
strcpy(dateHeure, "18/02/2016 15:02:05");
sscanf(dateHeure, "%d/%d/%d %d:%d:%d", (int*)&st.wDay, (int*)&st.wMonth, (int*)&st.wYear, (int*)&st.wHour, (int*)&st.wMinute, (int*)&st.wSecond);
```

It works for all st's members BUT st.wMonth : it does not receive any value. What's wrong ?

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Your casts invoke undefined behaviour. **Only cast iff** 1) they are absolutely necessary, 2) you know about **all** implications and 3) accept them. Instead use the correct type specifies in the format string.

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The structure SYSTEMTIME contains members whose types are `WORD`. That is a 16 bit unsigned integer.

Your code is passing the address of those members and casting them to int*. This is undefined behavior.

[According to Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#WORD), WORD is defined as an unsigned short.
This means the correct specifier for scanf() is `%hu`, and the casts should be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the type-casts, they are wrong.  `SYSTEMTIME` uses `WORD` for its fields.  `WORD` is a typedef for `unsigned short`, so you can use `%hu` instead of `%d`:

```
sscanf(dateHeure, "%hu/%hu/%hu %hu:%hu:%hu",
    &st.wDay, &st.wMonth, &st.wYear,
    &st.wHour, &st.wMinute, &st.wSecond);
```

Comment: Thank you : it works with %hu ! I give a green check to the previous answer but you have it too ! :-)